# How to highlight focused checkbox (tabindex)

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, tabs

My application have a few checkboxes, its more comfortable for the user
when he could use the tab key, to check the boxes. This works already.
But at the moment, the user can't see on which checkbox he is actually, only
when he press enter, he knows on which checkbox he is at the moment.
Is it possible to highlight the current chosen/focused checkbox with tab?

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= tasks; i++)
            {              
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                checkBox.Name = String.Format("chkBox_T{0}", i);
                checkBox.TabIndex = 0;
                checkBox.Text = "";
                checkBox.Autosize = true;
                checkBox.Location = new Point(ChkBoxX, chkBoxY);
                boundX_ChkBox += 26;
}
```

Comment: Hard to make sense of this, setting the Text property to an empty string surely doesn't make it a very usable UI.  You are otherwise re-inventing the DataGridView control, imperfectly.  ListView and TreeView also support checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the GotFocus and LostFocus event handlers, toggling the color.

```
checkBox.GotFocus += () => { checkBox.Color = <focuscolor> };
checkBox.LostFocus += () => { checkBox.Color = <originalcolor> };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the events GotFocus and LostFocus do not show up in VS (2015) when using the designer properties stuff. The events Enter and Leave are there - maybe MS is getting away from GotFocus and LostFocus? Dunno.

Here's a snip of what I created manually (with a check box named "checkBox_active":

```
// set up the handlers in your code at initialize time
      checkBox_active.GotFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox_active_GotFocus);
      checkBox_active.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox_active_LostFocus);


// code to handle the events
    private void checkBox_active_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      checkBox_active.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    private void checkBox_active_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      checkBox_active.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    }
```